# Getting file path in ASP.NET and XDocument.Load

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a static class in a folder off root in my solution. In that static class' folder, there's a subfolder containing XML files. So I've got these files:

```
/PartialViews/Header/MyStaticClass.cs
/PartialViews/Header/Config/en-US.xml
/PartialViews/Header/Config/jp-JP.xml
...
```

I'm having trouble using `XDocument.Load()` with those XML files. Specifically, I'm trying to load the XML files from the static constructor of `MyStaticClass`.

`XDocument.Load()` can't seem to find the files, however. I've tried all these and none work:

```
static MyStaticClass()
{
    XDocument doc;

    // These all throw exceptions relating to directory not found
    doc = XDocument.Load("/Config/en-US.xml");
    doc = XDocument.Load(@"\Config\en-US.xml");
    doc = XDocument.Load("/PartialViews/Header/Config/en-US.xml");
    doc = XDocument.Load(@"\PartialViews\Header\Config\en-US.xml");
}
```

I also tried using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` and `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` before the relative path, but the assembly resolved by `Assembly` is always a .NET library (because the type is being initialized?).

How can I load the file without changing its location in the solution?

Comment: Please leave tags like "C#" in the tags, and keep them out of the title. No reason to have the same information in two places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ASP.NET you should use Server.MapPath() to find all local files.

```
string relPath = "~/PartialViews/Header/Config/en-US.xml";
string absPath = Server.MapPath(relPath);

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(absPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

For .NET web apps use
`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");` this will get you the root directory of the executing file.